# Why use inherit for box-sizing in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I recently saw a website that used the following approach to set the CSS `box-sizing` property:

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I don't understand why someone would take this approach. Why wouldn't they just use the example below?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This give your more flexibility. You can add individual `box-sizing` styles to some elements and inherit for some.  Most of the elements will inherit from their parent and their parents from their parents, so on. Some will just have to use a different style. With HTML, you have to change the box-sizing at one place and most elements inheiritng will use that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using "inherit" for some css property then it will take the value of the same css property form it's parent element. So if value of some css property is same for both parent and child element then it's a good practice to user "inherit" for the child element because if you made some change in the same property to the parent element then the same change would be reflected to the child element , you don't need to make change at every places. Now here in the example that you have given , the coder want to use the same value ("border-box") for both child and parent element so he have done so.